# OSX - AFNetworking sending text even with JSON Serializer set

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, afnetworking

I have an issue with `AFNetworking` and `AFJSONRequestSerializer`. I try to access an API, and the request contains a `text/plain` header. Here's my code :

```
class BaseService {
    var manager: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager!

    init() {
        manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
        manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer(writingOptions: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros)
    }
}

class UserService: BaseService {
    func startNewEntry(name: String) {
        let params = [
            "time_entry": [
                "description": name,
                "created_with": "fooBar"
            ]
        ]

        manager.POST(
            "endpoint",
            parameters: params,
            success: { (operation, response) -> Void in

                let json = JSON(response)

                println("OK")
                println(json)

                Context.shared.entries.getFromJSON(json)

            }) { (operation, error) -> Void in
                println("-- ERROR --")
                println(operation)
                println(error)
            }
    }
```

Do you know this issue ?

Comment: How would we know what the issue is when you haven't explained what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this code will create a request with a content type of `application/json`. But I wonder if you perhaps mislead by an error message that said:

> Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html

If you got that, that's not telling you that that the request had an unacceptable content type, but rather that the request failed because *the response* was `text/html`. And this is a very common issue: If server code that is attempting to create a JSON response fails for some reason, sometimes the error message isn't JSON, but rather it's HTML.

I would suggest adding the following inside the `failure` block of your `POST` method in order to see what this `text/html` response was:

```
if operation.responseData != nil {
    println(NSString(data: operation.responseData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

This way, if you get a text error message from the server (e.g. the request was malformed or what have you), you'll be able to read the HTML response you got back.